# Typescript - Creating a Type That Narrows Another Type

Tags: typescript

I have a scenario where I want to have multiple types/interfaces that are all in the same structure:

```
type Base = {
  type: 'x' | 'y' | 'z'
  data: Record<string,string>
}
```

Now, I want to create types that "implements" this base type, while each of them narrows this type in different way:

```
type MyTypeX = {
  type: 'x'
  data: {
    specificKey: string
  }
}

type MyTypeY = {
  type: 'y'
  data: {
    otherKey: string
  }
}
```

But I can't find any good way to do that.
I know I can just use the types without having a base type, but I want to make sure that any of them has a "type" and "data" property and that each of them has a legal type. its like having a typesafe validation of other types. Is there any good way to do that? Is that even possible in TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use a generic type `Base`. Something like the following:

```
type Type = 'x' | 'y' | 'z';

type Base<T extends Type, D extends Record<string, string>> = {
  type: T;
  data: D;
};

type Foo = Base<'x', { specificKey: string }>;
type Bar = Base<'y', { otherKey: string }>;

const foo: Foo = { type: 'x', data: { specificKey: 'foo' }};
const bar: Bar = { type: 'y', data: { otherKey: 'bar' }};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oHIAeyoB8Ug95AXsgNwBQpokUAQgIYDOEAPDFBKsBAHYAm9s8ADRQAImw7c+UAEoQAxgHsATjyb1gSgJZcA5sPVbdAPiNQkAb1JQolCAC5YZaz1rBaDkWQC+ZCvCgAYgoKZjQMzGjIwuZQ9JBymgBmmnIA0hAgDgbaOlBeRmS2YUqhdIxMyLjRUArAABYQSumZsRo5eQXkilzqUInBDkEhFjbwDpHCLm4OMXHySSnN4-0KGF4+pN29AEa0Sg50JSO241VQU+5QMbUNTRnju0prG0A)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use interfaces, you can use the `extends` keyword, as in:

```
interface MyTypeX extends Base {
  type: 'x'
  data: {
    specificKey: string
  }
}
```

If you made something that was incompatible with Base (eg, you tried to do `type: boolean`), typescript will give an error where you define MyTypeX that MyTypeX incorrectly extends Base.

If you need to stick with types instead of interfaces, you could do an intersection of your type and the base type. If MyTypeX is incompatible with the base type, then MyTypeX will be `never`. This won't be an error where you define the type, but if you try to use the type you'll get errors.

```
type MyTypeX = Base & {
  type: 'x'
  data: {
    specificKey: string
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgpVJALigHIAPYqAHxJAuuIC9jtcATOYOIgJQgGMA9gCdWAHgTAhASwB2AcwA0E6fIB82AL7Zss4BCEAzOH2gBZEABVwEABpQIpPTNYJYiaJhx5rRMsy-snESeuLgIkHxSBlJ8ANIQIETKsnIsUFpYGToyeobG0PCs5laQdg5OLm5I6Gn4EEQARgICADYQcDIKaYFcNV5hEVEx8YlQyfJpGVlYdVDF1gCaUKjw1QBkfbh1vrTdHL0hoQLAABb6I0mSKZOa2jPWbkWWi8tV0BuH21BNre0ye0FNkdTucEpcVKkvFM7oIZBJ7KQ4ABbMBtIiFeaQJaoNDeQh4IQAVwgCigPWCUGOZyEFxIJykFA0GgA3EA)

Comment: Beat me to it, but here's a playground that demonstrates this: https://tsplay.dev/mb0K3w

Comment: Hah, i was just about to edit a playground link in :)

Comment: Not exactly true, as this method doesn't force the MyTypeX interface to override the `type` property, but instead it merges the Base interface with it. My question was about forcing one interface to "implement" another interface, just like we do with classes that implement interfaces